# iOS app - Non-Public API usage- app references non-public selectors: cancelButtonClicked, setResult:

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

After I have uploaded app to itunes i get mail saying that my app using non public api methods- **cancelButtonClicked**, **setResult:**

But cancelButtonClicked is used as IBAction method for various buttons and searchBar. Do I need to rename it? Also, this is very common please suggest..

For setResult: Method I have not used this method any where also, I haven't found this method used in my complete workspace.

I have used multiple third party APIs some of them are below:

- AFNetworking
- Google Maps SDK
- Google Places SDK
- Google Analytics
- RSK Image Cropper
- Facebook SDK
- Twitter SDK
- ASIHTTP
- MBProgressHud
- Reachability
- SDWebImageCache

Please suggest what I can do.

Also, I am using Xcode 6.3.2 with deployment target iOS 8.0. In some SO's answers it was suggested to use Xcode 6.0.1 but I can't use it as Google Maps SDK POD suggested to use Xcode6.3 or later.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?  How is cancelButtonClicked a private api call?

Comment: There was a method I have defined in one of my protocol named as cancelButtonClicked. This is causing issue with apple. Once I have renamed it issue is resolved.

Comment: @AvtarGuleria and what about setResult: was that also have been used by you? did you rename setResult also?

Answer (score 3):

You should make a search in your project directory for the method's call that you mentioned. This is a command line script to search in the whole project. This will return where these methods are called, and then you should modify the name of the method or update the library/framework containing the call.

```
grep -Rnis 'cancelButtonClicked' *
grep -Rnis 'setResult:' *
```

Comment: I have used cancelButtonClicked method as an IBAction in multiple view controllers. I think that is quite obvious to create IBAction for cancel button with same name, So it should not be the case

Comment: @TekayaMarouene thanks to your grep command recomendation I found the problematic framework. After trying unsuccessfully with "otool" and "strings" commands, "grep -R" gave me the solution! great answer!

Comment: PhysicianPortal_ios_build_new jenkins$ grep -Rnis 'etResult:' *
Binary file build/Physician Portal.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Physician Portal.app/Physician Portal matches
Binary file node_modules/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/Bolts.framework/Bolts matches
node_modules/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/Bolts.framework/Headers/BFTaskCompletionSource.h:37:- (void)setResult:(id)result;
node_modules/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/Bolts.framework/Headers/BFTaskCompletionSource.h:63:- (BOOL)trySetResult:(id)result;

Comment: Binary file node_modules/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit matches
Binary file platforms/ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Physician Portal/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Physician Portal.build/Release-iphoneos/Physician Portal.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Physician Portal matches
Binary file platforms/ios/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Physician Portal/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Physician Portal.build/Release-iphoneos/Physician Portal.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Physician Portal matches

Comment: Binary file platforms/ios/Physician Portal/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit matches
Binary file plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/Bolts.framework/Bolts matches
plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/Bolts.framework/Headers/BFTaskCompletionSource.h:37:- (void)setResult:(id)result;
plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/Bolts.framework/Headers/BFTaskCompletionSource.h:63:- (BOOL)trySetResult:(id)result;
Binary file plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook/src/ios/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit matches

Comment: Is it due to the Facebook plugin which our Developers have used? now, what to do next?